# How to loop a multidimensional array in a single cell apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have a 13 rows x 31 cell imported from a excel file and then store it inside arraylist so basically it is a 2d array like this

```
[1,2,3,4,5.................]
[a,b,c,d,e.................]
```

and then I convert it to String[] array like this

```
   String [] array = null;

      for (int rowNum = 1; rowNum <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); rowNum++) {
            Row r = sheet.getRow(rowNum);

            ArrayList<String> dl = new ArrayList<String>();

            for (int i = 3; i < r.getLastCellNum() + 1; i = i + 3) {
                Cell cell = r.getCell(i);
                val = formatter.formatCellValue(cell);
                dl.add(val);

                array = dl.toArray(new String[dl.size()]);

            }
            // send array as parameter to another method inside the same class
            WriteNewFile(array);
            break;
        }
```

in another method to create a new excel file, I have to loop the array than contain data like array data above.

```
 for (int x= 0; x<= total - 1; x++) {
        Row row3 = sheet.getRow( x+ 2);
        Cell cell1 = row3.createCell(3);
        cell1.setCellValue(array[x]);
    }
```

when I run this code, I got error message like this:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 32
```

the aim of my code is I want to print the array in a single cell and loop the row until total-1.

the value of total is 396

**UPDATED**

```
 for (int x= 0; x< array.length; x++) {
        Row row3 = sheet.getRow( x+ 2);
        Cell cell1 = row3.createCell(3);
        cell1.setCellValue(array[x]);
    }
```

the looping for the `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 32`
 has been solved.

back to the main question, now I able to print out the first row only

```
[1,2,3,4,5.................] //of this row
```

how to continue for the next row? Do I better convert it to 1d array?

**UPDATED**

now after received the array as the parameter send by other method to writeNewFile method(writeNewFile method only task is to write the new excel file using apache poi of the array data) and I can write the data like this:

```
|test|
  1
  2
  3
  4
  5
  6
```

supposedly I want to loop the array to be continue loop for the next row like this

```
|test|
  1
  2
  3
  4
  5
  6
  a
  b
  b
  d
  e
```

Comment: when `x` is equal to `total -1` as per your loop, then `x + 2` is obviously going to exceed this value

Comment: @ScaryWombat please refer to my update

Comment: same problem is going to exist

Comment: Where do you think you have a 2D array? I only see `String [] array` which is not 2D. And you are calling `WriteNewFile(array);` for each row having `array` a 1D array of strings. We need to know what `WriteNewFile` is doing to determine what row it writes. Btw: `WriteNewFile` should not be the name of a method. Method names should start lowercase `writeNewFile`. Names starting uppercase are class names.

Comment: @AxelRichter I am sorry. I am a totally beginner in programming world. I believe my arraylist data is 13row x 31cells. the array = dl.toArray(new String[dl.size()]); is I was trying to convert from arraylist to array because I need write every single data from the array which happens to have multirow array into a single cell while looping the row according to the data contain inside he array

Comment: @AxelRichter currently I can write the data only the first row of the array, but I cannot continue the next row of the array. thank you for telling me the name of the method btw

Comment: Your `String [] array` can only contain one row of data. And whoever wrote your code seems had have known this since `WriteNewFile(array)` is called for each single row. So we need to know what `WriteNewFile` is doing to be able to help.

Comment: @AxelRichter see my latest update. Hope it can help you

Comment: We need the code of `WriteNewFile` method.